# List Drupal Revisions

Tags: version-control

I just discovered the revisions function of Drupal. I tried it and the new revisions are stored in the database. I expected to get a list of revisions on the edit node page. But i don't see anything like this.

Is it possible to list and switch between revisions from within the UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are viewing a node that has revisions enabled, there will be a tab which will show all revisions of the current node.  If you want to see a list of all revisions on the site you could use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) to create a view of node revisions.  Then you can even add filters on content types, creation date, etc to customize your list.